# Which is the correct way to add item into ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapterview

Consider the following code.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, textViewResourceId, list);

// Method 1 : Add an item.
adapter.add("ITEM1");

// Method 2 : Add an item
list.add("ITEM2");
```

I was wondering, which is the correct way to add item into `ArrayAdapter`? As seems to me, both methods just work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 updates the associated `AdapterView`, if you have already attached the `ArrayAdapter` to the `AdapterView`. Method 2 does not, requiring you to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter`.

Typically, you populate the `ArrayList` before creating the `ArrayAdapter`, then use Method 1 to add new entries dynamically later on (e.g., based on user data entry).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, especially for my Search Results page - where it grows as the user scroll down (list changes).

I'd keep a local ArrayList of Strings that is global to the class,
Initialize the adapter (also locally and globally), 
Have a designated method alter the ArrayList of strings,
Then call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

This will not only update your list and also update the adapter to work in sync.

Hope this helps,

best,
-serkan